# Get data array from a Seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, kernel-density

I have used the seaborn pairplot function and would like to extract a data array.

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species")
```

I want to get an array of the points I show below in **black** color:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this line:

```
data = iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa']['sepal_length']
```

You are interested in the blue line, so the `'setosa'` scpecie. In order to filter the `iris` dataframe, I create this filter:

```
iris['species'] == 'setosa'
```

which is a boolean array, whose values are `True` if the corresponding row in the `'species'` columns of the `iris` dataframe is `'setosa'`, `False` otherwise. With this line of code:

```
iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa']
```

I apply the filter to the dataframe, in order to extract only the rows associated with the `'setosa'` specie. Finally, I extract the `'sepal_length'` column:

```
iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa']['sepal_length']
```

If I plot a KDE for this data array with this code:

```
data = iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa']['sepal_length']
sns.kdeplot(data)
```

I get:

[image]

that is the plot above you are interested in

The values are different from the plot above by the way KDE is calculated.
I quote this [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/histograms-and-density-plots-in-python-f6bda88f5ac0):

> The y-axis in a density plot is the probability density function for
> the kernel density estimation. However, we need to be careful to
> specify this is a probability density and not a probability. The
> difference is the probability density is the probability per unit on
> the x-axis. To convert to an actual probability, we need to find the
> area under the curve for a specific interval on the x-axis. Somewhat
> confusingly, because this is a probability density and not a
> probability, the y-axis can take values greater than one. The only
> requirement of the density plot is that the total area under the curve
> integrates to one. I generally tend to think of the y-axis on a
> density plot as a value only for relative comparisons between
> different categories.

Comment: And why in the matrix graph does it reach a maximum value of 8 and isolated has a maximum value of 1.2?